# AngularJS "sendJavascript" cordova plugin call a factory function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a Cordova plugin that do some webservice thinks, and i want it to make a call a angular factory function on the WebView using the sendJavascript android command.

I have another project where it works without angularjs.

**AngularJS factory**

```
....
.factory('playerService', function(){
    var title = "Tryk på play";

    var setTitle = function(t) {
        title = t;
    }
    var getTitle = function() {
        return title;
    }

    return {
        setTitle : setTitle,
        getTitle : getTitle
    }
})
....
```

**Cordova plugin**

```
....
cordova.webView.sendJavascript("javascript: playerService.setTitle('test test');
....
```

I got a "playerService" is not defined - in the logcat android output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got a solution ...

1) First i got to select a element in the DOM witch is in the scope. In my example i have an div with the ID playbuttons

```
cordova.webView.sendJavascript("javascript: angular.element(document.querySelector('#playbuttons')).scope().$apply(function() {angular.element(document.querySelector('#playbuttons')).scope().playerService.setTitle('TESTING')})");
```

I think this i very hacky, so if anyone can correct me, the feel free ;)